# Can I make Jachnun in a Dutch oven?

Tags: pastry

[Jachnun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jachnun) is prepared from dough which is rolled out thinly, brushed with clarified butter, rolled up and baked overnight. The preparation calls for a [Jachnun pot](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01BC2LIYG).

Trouble is, I don't own a Jachnun pot, and I don't feel like paying for a pot that I can only use for one dish, that I've never made before, and might decide never to make again. I want to try making Jachnun once.

I do own a cast iron Dutch oven. Can I use that instead? What difference would it make? Aluminium has different heat conductivity from cast iron, but considering I'm sticking the thing in the oven on 100C for 15 hours, what difference would heat conductivity make?

Comment: I'm thinking heat up and cool down times would BOTH be longer. You probably could though, I would be tempted to take them out shortly after removing from the oven as the cast iron would keep it warmer longer...

Comment: I don't thing iron vs. aluminum would make a difference, but the Jachunin pots I know of have a lid that seals very tightly, much more tightly than a cast iron dutch oven.  So you might need to do something to create a better seal.

Comment: @FuzzyChef Any ideas for making a better seal?

Comment: Either tin foil or dough.  Dough works better, but then you need to scrape it off afterwards.

Comment: Alternately, if you have a stovetop pressure cooker, just use that, sans valve.  Those seal great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While a jachnun pot is traditional, many recipes mention alternatives:

- "an [oven proof pot](https://www.fromthegrapevine.com/israeli-kitchen/recipes/how-make-jachnun-yemenite-israeli-experience)"
- "grease [a pan that has a cover or use aluminum foil](https://www.joyofkosher.com/browse/how-to-cook-jachnun-and-what-to-serve-it-with/)"
- "a 9 inch by 13 inch [cake pan or casserole](https://www.karenskitchenstories.com/2017/02/jachnun.html)"
- "Generally, jachnun is baked in a round oven-safe metal pot with a tight-sealing lid, but I've also had fine results baking it [in a crockpot](https://forward.com/food/151041/jachnun-yemens-shabbat-bread-transformed/)."
- "1 [steel pot](http://www.mayaskitchen.info/2012/05/23/jachnun-a-yemenite-brunch/) (pot and lid made of steel)" (included mostly because it's material-specific, but not aluminum)
- "an [8-inch springform pan](https://www.thespruceeats.com/uri-schefts-yemenite-jachnun-dairy-4117373)"

The key to preparation really seems to be the low and slow bake temperature and time. A well-sealed lid may date from a time when this was cooked in the embers of a fire; covering the jachnun rolls while they bake is universally recommended, but a very tight seal does not seem to be critical.